# Error when trying to convert mp3 (and image) to mp4 using ffmpeg SPACES IN NAME

Tags: loops, batch-file, ffmpeg, spaces

I found how to batch convert MP3s to MP4s using the code below in a batch file:

```
for %%f in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i %%f -loop 1 -i image.jpg -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest %%~nf.mp4
```

It works fine UNLESS the FILENAME has spaces in it: FILENAME.mp3 works fine but FILE NAME.mp3 gives the error "No such file or directory."

I tried inserting the "delims=" before and after the %%f but it keeps saying that it is unexpected.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: put quotes around the filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%f in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -loop 1 -i image.jpg -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest "%%~nf.mp4"
```

In general `"quote filenames that may contain spaces"`

`"delims="` can only be used with `for /f` as in

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (...
```

Where the porpose of the `for` is primarily to read lines from the files.

use `'dir /b /a-d filemask'` - including the quotes to provide `for /f`  with a listing of filenames to process. The `/b` means "basic form" (names only) and `/a-d` means "no directories".

If your filenames contain separators like spaces, use `"delims=" otherwise the implicit "tokens=1" will truncate the value applied at the first separator.

Comment: Consider adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as an output option. Otherwise the output may use a chroma subsampling scheme that dumb players can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help, the quotes are what did the trick.

I changed this:

```
for %%f in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i %%f -loop 1 -i image.jpg -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest %%~nf.mp4
```

To this:

```
for %%f in ("*.mp3") do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -loop 1 -i image.jpg -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -flags global_header -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest "%%~nf.mp4"
```

FYI: Extra toggles were added but had nothing to do with the spaces causing issues:

```
-flags global_header -pix_fmt yuv420p
```